# How can I determine the current brew package count?

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, open-source

I tried to get the number of available `brew` packages by running

```
brew search | wc -l
```

but I don't know how accurate this really is. What do I need to take into account to get a more correct number?

PS: macports lists 19,889 packages online [here](https://www.macports.org/ports.php)

Comment: Asking for "what is the output of `brew search | wc -l`" is off-topic as it doesn't show any kind of research on your part (you can easily run this yourself) nor does it seem to be related to a practical problem.That's why I (as well as @bmike) edited it into something which might be of interest to a wider audience. Please have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/editing to understand why editing happens.

Comment: @patrix, I'd have to install macOS first.

Comment: So it's a kind of hypothetical question then :-) `brew` is just a bunch of shell and ruby scripts, will run anywhere with some tweaking. And the result is changing daily, right now it's 4557.

Comment: This is really a Wikipedia question so let’s pause it in time. There is an answer that explains well how the system functions, so there’s no need to delete this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On June 23, 2019 the soon to be incorrect count of packages is **4804**.

Since many people add and remove packages, this count shifts by dozens a day and sometimes hundreds at a time when larger changes move packages out of the mainstream repository into a sub repository that can be "tapped" to increase the count.

Homebrew uses a concept called tap, which is simply a repository containing a list of formulae that it tracks, updates, and installs from. The default installation of Homebrew comes with a tap called **homebrew/core** but there's no limit to how many or how large a tap you could source packages since they can be self hosted pretty much anywhere.

Running `brew [command] [options]` runs the command on **homebrew/core** tap. There are various other official and unofficial taps from which packages can be installed.

The total count of packages in any tap keeps changing as new packages (called formula) are added, deleted or updated. To get the current count, first update the local **homebrew/core** tap repository by running:

`brew update`.

Now execute your command-line:

`brew search | wc -l`

to get the current count of packages in the **homebrew/core** tap. Running `brew search` without any arguments lists all the packages (formula).

Comment: I've edited the question a bit to make it more general. Do you have any details on how to get a list of taps and the number of packages within them you could add?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @patrix. Due to the way Homebrew is designed, there is no **fixed** set of taps. A tap can be easily created with the help of a hosted git repository and an installation of Homebrew can **tap** into it! There are a few official taps maintained by Homebrew community, but no website (even official) publishes the count of formula in a tap as it is highly dynamic.